# ThreadPoolExecutor in python is not executing all tasks

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to download a bunch of Sentinel 2 images from Copernicus and since it is a slow process, I'm using multi-threading. The function below sends an image request to the Copernicus database and the response is then saved into my hard disk.

```
import concurrent.futures

start_dates = ["2023-12-26","2023-10-07","2023-09-07","2023-08-16","2023-07-07"]
end_dates = ["2023-12-27","2023-10-08","2023-09-08","2023-08-17","2023-07-08"]

def process_requests(start_date: str, end_date: str) -> None:
    # aoi is just a polygon and the access token is obtained after sending credentials

    df = request_sentinel2(start_date, end_date, aoi, access_token)
    sentinel_id = get_sentinel_L2A_id(df)
    date = get_image_date(df)
    url = generate_sentinel_URL(sentinel_id)

    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"}
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
    write_response_to_file(response, f"sentinel_{date}.zip")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process_requests, start_dates, end_dates)
```

I originally wanted to download images for 12 dates, but when I run my code it only performs 4 tasks and then it stops without performing the 12 tasks. The program does not crash... It creates 12 files but 4 of them are complete and the remaining 8 have only 1Kb of data. Thus, in order to download everything I have to send only 4 dates and then run it again for another 4 dates and so on. My pc has 10 cores and 12 logical processes.
Since I'm new to multithreading I would love to know why this happens, if it's normal or not and how to solve it eventually.

Comment: What do you mean by "it stops"? Does it run to completion? Is there an exception? Add some debug prints to show where you are in the code and also some relevant values. Also, your use of a requests.Session is dubious. You don't really need it but if you insist on using it, be sure to close it when you're done

Comment: Is it possible that the website only allows a certain request rate to prevent denial of service attacks and you have exceeded that rate? As an aside, better to create the `requests.Session` only once and pass it to each thread so that all threads can share the same session. Change `executor.map(process_requests, start_dates, end_dates)` to `list(executor.map(process_requests, start_dates, end_dates))`, which will check to see if any of your tasks has raised an exception.

Comment: @CtrlZ Sorry, I will edit. It does NOT crash, it finishes but does not really perform all tasks.

Comment: @stray_dog where do you check the HTTP response code?

Comment: @CtrlZ Both of you are right. I hadn't check the response status code properly. I'm getting 429 for some requests which, according to the Copernicus API, is delivered when the request limit is exceeded (something that Booboo already suggested) 
Thank you guys.